# Tkinter Buttons's command don't working after bind_class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to make my gui more beatifull and there is problem with `bind_class`.

My `bind_class` code is below;

```
mainWindow.bind_class('Button', '<Enter>', onCursorButton)
mainWindow.bind_class('Button', '<Leave>', notCursorButton, add='+')
```

Here's my functions;

```
def onCursorButton(event):
  lighter = hex_to_hsv(event.widget['background'])
  lighter_list = list(lighter)
  if not (lighter[1]-0.4) <= 0:
    lighter_list[1] = lighter_list[1]-0.4
  if not (lighter[2]+0.4) >= 1:
    lighter_list[2] = lighter_list[2]+0.4
  lighter = tuple(lighter_list)
  event.widget.config(bg=hsv_to_hex(lighter))

def notCursorButton(event):
  event.widget.config(bg=generalBtnColor)
```

This function is work better than I execpted but after, these buttons's own command is not working.

```
bgButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                     bg=generalBgColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(1, generalBgColor))

fgButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                     bg=generalFgColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(2, generalFgColor))

btnButton = tk.Button(themeWindow, text=' ', relief='ridge',
                      bg=generalBtnColor, width=6, command=lambda: pickColor(3, generalBtnColor))
```

And yes, normally this buttons were perfect working.

Comment: I think you just need the `add='+'` option for both bindings.  Buttons have a built-in binding for `<Enter>`, you're currently preventing that from ever being invoked, and apparently it's doing something critical for the normal click functionality.

Comment: Oh thanks, that fixed my problem. But why? How it is possible to effect button's self command?